# Warning error of "plot.new has not been called yet" when attempting to plot ecdf for a variable

Tags: r, plot, ecdf

I am having difficulty plotting an `ECDF` function for a variable.  The simple code below provides an example;

```
A = rnorm(100)
plot(ecdf(A),
     abline(v=c(-1,1,1.5)))
```

When I attempt to plot the function with vertical lines the warning message

> Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) :
>   plot.new has not been called yet

appears.

I have searched a number of sources but I have not been able to identify what mistake I am making.  If anyone could provide information on how to plot these `ecdf` plots and then add vertical lines I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is a syntax error. Try this for example `plot(ecdf(A));abline(v=c(-1,1,1.5))`

Comment: `abline` is a function on its own, not a value you want to pass to one of the arguments of the `plot` function.

Comment: @agstudy Your answer is the correct one, I recommend you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Everything is correct except that you first have to plot the graph

```
plot(ecdf(A))
```

And then you can add the `abline`. As Roland said, `abline` is not a function of plot (in contrast to `ggplot2`)

```
abline(v=c(-1,1,1.5)))
```